# Trouble with getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE) - Already implemented context

Tags: android, gyroscope

I'm trying to create a Service for my Gyroscope in Android, but I keep having trouble with getSystemService.

I've been searching through the forums, trying to find a solution, but in most cases it is a matter of simply importing the context from the MainActivity.

```
public class GyroData implements SensorEventListener {

private final Context mContext;
protected SensorManager mSensorManager;

public GyroData(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
}
```

As you can see above, I've already done that, yet I'm still getting the following error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{sw806f16.p8project/sw806f16.p8project.CameraActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
at sw806f16.p8project.GyroData.setupSensorManager(GyroData.java:24)
```

EDIT: Added code from MainActivity

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
public static final String TAG = "CameraActivity";

LocationService gps = new LocationService(this);
GyroData gyro = new GyroData(this);
```

Comment: The problem is with where you're instantiating `GyroData`, not the `GyroData` class itself.

Comment: Could you explain further because I'm not really seeing it.

Comment: Please post the relevant code from `MainActivity`.

Comment: Done, added as an Edit

Comment: Move the `gyro` initialization to `onCreate()`, after the call to `super.onCreate()`. You should do the same with the `gps` initialization.

Comment: Tested and it works. Thanks a lot! If you want you can add your last comment as an answer so that I can Accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're instantiating `GyroData` in `CameraActivity`'s `<init>` method; that is, outside of any method. This happens before any defined methods are called, including `onCreate()`, and the `super.onCreate()` call therein, which must occur before you can request system services, as you are in `GyroData`'s constructor.

Simply move the `gyro` initialization to `onCreate()`, after the call to `super.onCreate()`. You should do the same with the `gps` initialization.